# How to search for content in XPath in multiline text using Python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

When I search for the existence of data in text() of an element using contains, it works for plain data but not when there are carriage returns, new lines/tags in the element content. How to make `//td[contains(text(), "")]` work in this case? Thank you!

**XML :**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hello world <i> how are you? </i>
      Have a wonderful day.
      Good bye!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Hello NJ <i>, how are you?
      Have a wonderful day.</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Python :**

```
>>> tdout=open('tdmultiplelines.htm', 'r')
>>> tdouthtml=lh.parse(tdout)
>>> tdout.close()
>>> tdouthtml
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x2aaae0024368>
>>> tdouthtml.xpath('//td/text()')
['\n      Hello world ', '\n      Have a wonderful day.\n      Good bye!\n    ', '\n      Hello NJ ', '\n    ']
>>> tdouthtml.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Good bye")]')
[]  ##-> But *Good bye* is already in the `td` contents, though as a list.
>>> tdouthtml.xpath('//td[text() = "\n      Hello world "]')
[<Element td at 0x2aaae005c410>]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//td[text()[contains(.,'Good bye')]]
```

**Explanation**:

The reason for the problem is not that a text node's string value is a multiline string -- the real reason is that the `td` element has more than one text-node children.

**In the provided expression**:

```
//td[contains(text(),"Good bye")]
```

**the first argument passed to the function `contains()` is a node-set of more than one text nodes**.

As per XPath 1.0 specification (in XPath 2.0 this simply raises a type error), a the evaluation of a function that expects a string argument but is passed a node-set instead, *takes the string value only of the 1st node in the node-set*.

**In this specific case, the first text node of the passed node-set has string value**:

```
 "
                 Hello world "
```

**so the comparison fails and the wanted `td` element isn't selected**.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//td[text()[contains(.,'Good bye')]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Hello world <i> how are you? </i>
          Have a wonderful day.
          Good bye!
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Hello NJ <i>, how are you?
          Have a wonderful day.</i>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (in this case just one) are copied to the output**:

```
<td>
          Hello world <i> how are you? </i>
          Have a wonderful day.
          Good bye!
        </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! //td[text()[contains(.,'Good bye')]] is analogous to this //td[contains(.,"Good bye")] as I see it. Choosing this as answer for helping me and others to understand this!

Comment: @ThinkCode: You are welcome. Actually, `//td[contains(.,"Good bye")]` may lead to false positives, because `.` is converted to the *string value* of the context node. If the element has more than one text node descendents, all of them are concatenated in forming its string value. You may not be wanting an element selected if it has two consecutive text-node descendents the first ending in a starting substring of the search string and the second starting in the rest of the search string.

Comment: Hmmm, I am a little bit confused. Can you please give us an example showing the difference between both the implementations? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ThinkCode: `<x>string1<y>string2string3</y>` and you are looking for a text node that contains `string1string2`

Comment: In your ex. : //td[text()[contains(.,'xxxxx')]] looks in 'string1 string2string3' whereas //td[contains(.,"xxxxx")]  looks in 'string1string2string3'?

Comment: @ThinkCode: In my solution I check if there is *any* text node that contains (entirely in itself) the whole search string. So, if you were searching, say, for "core" and there were two consecutive text nodes: "Humphry & co" and "related", the other solution would select the parent of these text nodes -- while my solution wouldn't.

Comment: Perfectly, exactly what I am looking for! Thank you so much! This shall really help others given that Python+XPath documented examples aren't so many.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.` instead of `text()`:

```
tdouthtml.xpath('//td[contains(.,"Good bye")]')
```

Comment: what does those dot mean ?