# More pythonic way to pick multiple element types from tagged data

Tags: python, lxml

I have some tagged data that I am processing using lxml.  When I open a file I do not know before the file is opened if I have one or more of three types of elements (I could have one, two or three different elements and multiple instances of any type I have)

I need some information about these elements that is contained in child tags of the element

```
<element_type_1>
        <name>joe smith</name>
</element_type_1>
<element_type_2>
        <name>mary smith</name>
</element_type_2>
<element_type_3>
        <name>patrick smith</name>
</element_type_3>
```

So in this case I have all three types but only one of each type however there could be up to some arbitrary large number of any type.

I am getting the elements by using `cssselect` 3 times in my function

```
def get_types(myTree):
    type_dict=defaultdict(list)
    type_dict['type_1']=myTree.cssselect('element_type_1')
    type_dict['type_2']=myTree.cssselect('element_type_2')
    type_dict['type_3']=myTree.cssselect('element_type_3')
    ret type_dict
```

This seems overly redundant

Am I missing something that would clean up this a bit?

FYI I am doing this because for each type I have to match some other data from a related document

The early answers suggest I need to clarify a bit - I want to avoid running through the tree three times

Comment: Do you have to use csselect? Otherwise an XPath expression with `contains('element_type_')` might do the trick better? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106971/how-to-search-for-content-in-xpath-in-multiline-text-using-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for i in range(1, 4):
    type_dict['type_%d' % i] = myTree.cssselect('element_type_%d' % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you know how it looks. Using an variable as key might be a simple thing to help you improve it a tiny bit.

```
def get_types(myTree):
    type_dict=defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(1,4):
      x = 'type_%d' % i
      y = 'element_type_%d' % i
      type_dict[x] = myTree.csselect(y)
    return type_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you identify these "types" if you don't know their names in advance. Do they follow some fixed pattern you can search for?

For example, you can do something like this:

```py
d = {}
typeelements = "*[starts-with(local-name(), 'element_type_')]"
for e in myTree.xpath(typeelements)
    typename = e.tag.split('_',1)[1]
    d[typename] = e
```

Or more succinctly:

```py
d = {e.tag.split('_',1)[1]:e for e in myTree.xpath(typeelements)}
```

Alternatively, you can select the element based on some criteria in the element itself. IUn your example they all have `name` children, so you can use a path like this:

```py
typeelements = '*[name]'
```

Or you can combine both requirements:

```py
typeelements = "*[starts-with(name(), 'element_type_')][name]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could iterate over a set of known tags looking for matching elements.  When you find an element, add (tag, value) to the dict.  Should work OK.