# xpath to get checkbox inside label

Tags: text, xpath, label

I have this code

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="fOejPdlZIx83HA" name="btnRad">
  Test1
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="fdsaf4waff4sssd" name="btnRad">
  Test2
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="fg43fasd43wsat4" name="btnRad">
  Test3
</label>
```

I wish to access the radio button depending on the label text via xpath

I already tried multiple thing:

```
//input[@name='btnRad]']/following::*[contains(text(),'Test3')]
//label[text()='Test3']/input[@name='btnRad']
//*[contains(text(),'Test3')]
```

Even the last one return me nothing, so xpath think that "Test3" is not the text of the label... anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: i tested the last xpath query in firefox using the great plugin FirePath and it works

Comment: I seriously don't know what to tell you... I tried the last one with firepath too, and it return no result :/

Comment: i tested in this same page and it works, very weird...

Comment: I'm using firefox 24 on debian 7.3... I'm gonna install firepath on windows and try it...

Comment: I'm using firefox 26 on windows 7

Comment: If this work on your computer, this is the weirdest thing... firefox 26 and 27 on windows does not work either

Comment: .//*[@id='question']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/pre[1]/code/span[67] this is the xpath returned

Comment: upss, i create a separate html file with your code and did'nt work, let me check why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expression is failing because your `label` has more that one text node: an empty string before the `input`, and `Test3`. The way you're using `contains` means it will only check the **first text node**, ie empty string.

Two ways of solving this:

- eliminating the empty strings with `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  //*[contains(text()[normalize-space()], 'Test3')]
  ```
- querying each `text()`:

  ```
  //*[text()[contains(.,'Test3')]]
  ```

For a more detailed explanation, see [How to search for content in XPath in multiline text using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106971/how-to-search-for-content-in-xpath-in-multiline-text-using-python).

Answer (score 0):

This works also `//label[contains(.,'Test3')]/input` .